# Browser cleanup like CCleaner using VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, internet-explorer, browser, mozilla

I'm working on a VB.NET application  and I need to delete all cookies, Internet caches and auto-complete keywords **from all browsers** found in the system. What are the folders I should be deleting content from?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Install any browser you want to support in your app and then check where it stores the data you want to delete. Also check the documentation of the browser (path might depend on OS, whatever).
Since it's easy to write your "own" browser (using 3rd party rendering engine), you will never be able to support **all browsers found in the system**.